# How to get logging in Twisted logger based application working nicely with Crossbar

Tags: logging, twisted, crossbar

I'm using WAMP for an application where much of the application logic is divided over a number of microservices connected using the Crossbar WAMP broker (version 0.15.0 with Twisted 16.3.0 on OSX 10.11.6).

I'm implementing logging for this application using Twisted's Logger functionality where I use a number of custom observers added to the globalLogPublisher to filter log records and store them in a database.

The problem that I'm having is that I do not get this application logger to work nicely together with Crossbar's logger that also uses the Twisted Logger framework.
Crossbar now is in control of the logging process. For the loglevel for instance  I have to set the loglevel for Crossbar to debug in order to debug my application. I find this undesirable because Crossbar itself is very noisy in debug mode making it hard to spot debug messages from my application.
I could use namespaces and loglevel filtering but it is my believe that Crossbar, being a service in my application, should not be in control of the logging process.

I would like to know if and how I can get control back. Being able to set a debug loglevel for my application while Crossbar's own loglevel stays at info level would be really helpful.

An overview of the logging architecture of my application:

1. The application is a Python package here called 'application'
2. In the package __main__.py the application is started. For logging this means:

   - Add two custom observers as described [here](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/core/howto/logger.html#implementing-an-observer)
   - The applications microservices implemented as wamplets (as in this [example](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/work/wamplet1)) are bootstrapped. Each microservice uses Twisted logger for logging.
3. In the last two lines of __main__.py the Crossbar cli controller is imported (from crossbar.controller.cli import run) and the Crossbar event loop is started (run()).
4. The application is thus started as: python application start (*any crossbar cli arguments here*)

Comment: can you share minimal working example of your code? this will certainly help people answer your question and understand what happens

Comment: A minimal working example is a bit difficult considering the full Crossbar stack and microservices but I have added a overview of the logging architecture of my application that will hopefully give a bit more insight in the steps that may lead to the behavior I'm experiencing.

Comment: Would love to know if you can up with a solution for this - I'm dealing with the same issue.